# How can I make a drawing surface so people can draw on my Windows Form application?

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

I'm making a simple chat program for me and my friends as a tech demo. I had the idea to have a small drawing pad thing that would be shared between all connected users.

What could I use in this situation (control wise)?

I know I can convert an image to a byte[] and pass that to everyone, but I'd need to use a pictureBox to get said image.

Thanks for the help! Doesn't have to be step by step instruction, just a guideline.

Comment: How about looking at the code of free VNC apps? You will get enough to read there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is lot more to write here that just passing arrays. The syncing of the picture needs to be fast and passing array is not the best idea. Instead, try sending events to each chat client.

There are many ways. You have to decide which is fast enough for you.

Study TightVNC's source code to gain in-depth knowledge. [Here is the link.](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.html)